# How to re-define the chapter-mark without changing the Appendix heading?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

The document is `book` class and the Appendix is added by:

```
 ...
\backmatter 
\appendix
\chpater{Appendix A}
  ...
\chpater{Appendix B}
  ...
```

Using `fancyhdr`:

```
\usepackage[]{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{} 

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection ~ \ #1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{ \chaptername\ \thechapter ~ \ #1}{}} 

%head setting
\fancyhead[LE]{\textcolor{black} {\thepage}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textcolor{black} {\itshape \nouppercase  \leftmark}}%higher level \scshape  \MakeUppercase
\fancyhead[LO]{\textcolor{black} {\itshape \nouppercase  \rightmark}} 
\fancyhead[RO]{\textcolor{black} {\thepage}}   %odd page
```

The chapter-mark is expected to be re-defined  like `Chapter 2  State of the art`, However, the `\chaptername` will appear in Appendix heading.

So how to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: In the `book` class, `\backmatter` will remove the "Chapter" (or "Appendix") prefix. If the question is still relevant, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: This is *not* a bug. You're surely defining your personalized headings, so it's necessary to know how you do it.

Comment: Is the command spelled `\chpater` on purpose?

Comment: \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection ~ \ #1}} and \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter ~ \ #1}{}} used to define section and chapter mark. However, if I comment these commands, the Appendix heading becomes Appendix. Appendix A.

Comment: @KOF The code in the question and in the last comment don't agree. Which one are you using?

Comment: The original `fancyhdr` setting is attached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a test for the `mainmatter` switch to the definition of `\chaptermark`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~~#1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\if@mainmatter\chaptername\ \thechapter~~\fi#1}{}}
\makeatother

\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\itshape\nouppercase  \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\itshape\nouppercase  \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\backmatter

\chapter{Appendix~A}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}​
```